# How to set :hover for all elements

Tags: html, css

Why does this doesn't work?

```
*:hover {margin-left:50px;}
```

Cause when I move over the element nothing happened.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/8bfPS/ In my opinion, it is not a very good idea to implement it this way. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: are you wanting each individual item to have a hover state, or a hover state once the page is hovered on and all items shift left?

Comment: Let's flip the question: Why *wouldn't* it work?

Comment: Why on earth would you wanna do this? :P

Comment: To better see the hover effect i changed the border on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld9kn/

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below

```
body *:hover {margin-left:50px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you putting it at the end of your CSS file?  If not, it may be getting overwritten.

```
*:hover {
    margin-left: 50px;
 }
```

is working for me.
What browser are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
body :hover{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

this will apply the *:hover* to every inner element in body

I've just tested on Chrome and seems to work